How to Prevent a Domain User from Logging into Other Domain Users' Computers?
I'm currently managing a Windows domain environment, and I've encountered an issue where a domain user can log into any other domain user's computer. This poses a security concern for us, and we would like to restrict this ability.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to configure the domain or group policies to prevent domain users from logging into computers that are not assigned to them? Ideally, we want to limit users to only log into their own designated machines.
Thanks in advance for your help!

and I've encountered an issue where a domain user can log into any other domain user's computer - This is the default behavior. This poses a security concern for us, and we would like to restrict this ability. - Can you elaborate on your concerns? Ideally, we want to limit users to only log into their own designated machines. - See here: https://activedirectorypro.com/restrict-user-logon-to-specific-computers/
